# Team Foundation Server 2015 install error with SQL Server 2017 Express TF400533

Tags: tfs, sql-server-express

Installing TFS Server on Win10 box with SQL Server 2017 Express already installed and detected by the TFS installer.

Then I get this error:

> TF400533: The SQL Server Express instance installed on this machine cannot be upgraded to the latest version of SQL Server Express until you have applied a more recent service pack to it. It is recommended that you run Microsoft Update, which will install the most recent service pack for you automatically, then re-run this wizard. For more information on upgrade requirements for SQL Server Express, visit: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301277.

Does anyone have any idea how to work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

TFS2015 will not install on a new DB server like this SQL Server 2017 Express I found out after searching to find the install docs.